# Copying of data in a tight loop where the function "Move" can not be used

Tags: assembly, x86, freepascal

In one of my software projects I am in "the need of" the best possible speed for a tight loop which copies indexed data from an array into a different part of the same array.

Please consider this freepascal code:

```
TYPE
  tIndex : ARRAY OF BYTE;
  tValues: ARRAY OF CARDINAL;

VAR
  Index : tIndex;
  Values: tValues;

CONST
  AnyCardinalSize = 65535;   

PROCEDURE InitializeArrays;
  BEGIN
    SetLength(Index, AnyCardinalSize);
    SetLength(Values,AnyCardinalSize);
  END;

PROCEDURE MoveData(CONST StartPosition,EndPosition,TargetPosition : CARDINAL);
  VAR {Note: TargetPosition is ALWAYS larger than EndPosition.}
    x, InsertOffset : CARDINAL;
  BEGIN
    InsertOffset := TargetPosition-StartPosition;
    FOR x := StartPosition TO EndPosition DO BEGIN
      Values[x+InsertOffset] := Values[Index[x]];
    END;
  END;
```

My routine `MoveData` work as intended, but I would like to investigate the possibility of replacing it with assembler code in order to gain a little bit of speed, if at all possible.

If somebody has examples of how this can be done in assembler language then I would be most grateful. I did some ASM on the Commodore 64, but that is a lifetime ago.

Comment: Why do you feel that hand rolled asm will do better than the compiler?

Comment: And it really does make a difference to know which compiler you use. Which is it?

Comment: I use Lazarus Version 1.4RC1, with FPC Version 2.6.4.

Comment: Let me try again. Why do you feel that the code emitted by the compiler is inefficient? You have not even shown that code.

Comment: Hand Rolled ASM outperform compilers in most every setting unless the compiler recognizes some code that has already been optimized as ASM-code and then used/inserted by the compiler.
I am sure that you also know this David.
And... because my ASM is too rusty, I asked for help. Is that not the aim of StackOverflow?

Comment: I wasn't even aware that I could have a look at my procedure as a compiled result. How do I do that?

Comment: A good compiler is perfectly capable of producing code to read and write data efficiently. And no, Stack Overflow isn't about getting others to write code because they are missing certain skills. It's a Q&A resource for use by others, not just you. A good question will have value for future readers that aren't you. This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: If you want to look at the code that is emitted, you'll want a disassembler. The Delphi IDE has one. I think that Lazarus will have one also. Debug your program (compiled for release, with optimisations enabled) and look for the CPU view or similar.

Comment: One thing that you might look into is writing the code in another language that has compilers known to optimise very well. Compare the emitted code, and compare the performance. That's a good way to get a feel for whether or not there is much scope for improvement.

Comment: So. Basically what you say, David, is that questions regarding how to do certain things is invalid because they don't offer other users anything?
This question from me have just turned out to be a kind of fight like "Why do you want to know," and you seem to be the God above all, deciding what are good and what are bad questions.
Examples of code can be useful! It would show how:
1. Parameters are transferred to ASM.
2. Variables/Arrays are addressed in ASM.
3. Create loops in ASM.
Most important, show how this can be done inside a procedure or function in Lazarus/Delphi

Comment: No that's not what I said at all. Your question reads as though you want us to write your code for you. That's not what SO is about. Covered in the [help] and ad nauseum on meta. I suggest you spend some time there to find out more. I would like you to explain why you feel that asm will offer a benefit. You won't do so, and instead say that since you know nothing about asm you'd like us to write the code for you. How will that benefit anybody? Anyway, if you don't want to listen to me, and insist that this question is fine as it is, fine. Good luck.

Comment: First thing is to analyze the asm code by the disassembler: [Lazarus IDE Window: Assembler](http://wiki.freepascal.org/IDE_Window:_Assembler)

Comment: Second, read the [documentation](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/3.0.0/prog/progch3.html) how to use assembly with freepascal.

Comment: Why not use move? Google `rep movsd`, or `db 66h rep movsd` assuming you're in 16bit DOS. And don't trust youf compiler. You're makinv thd righg choicd wantinb to inline code manually.

Comment: David. I did not ask people to write the code for me. I asked for examples of how this can be done...
I have also not said that I don't know anything about ASM. I just don't know enough.
If you have decided that my question is totally without value for anybody, then why bother replying? This whole discussion is like you "denying me" "the right to know" the tensile strength of a rope without me telling you what I am going to lift first!. Most of this discussion is just time consuming and off topic. If you don't want to share your knowledge, then that's fine with me.

Comment: Asking for examples is off-topic.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by using two array's and using values from one as an index to move items in the other one? Are you memory constrainted, cpu constrained, other? It looks like you are creating a datastructure on your own while there's a multitude of performant and tested solutions available. What is wrong with them?

Comment: You are asking us to write the code for you. If you aren't an expert in this then who else is going to write the code? You won't be able to, because it needs an expert. Do you want to learn how to do this yourself, or do you just want some code? And why can't we see what the compiler emits? Did you compare the code produced by other compilers? Do you have sample data and timing comparisons? On the face of it, it doesn't look like you are trying hard enough. Unless you can show some commitment by investigating in the manner described, then it does feel like you just want code.

Comment: Well. Lieven Keersmaekers. Your comment is just another one that is totally avoiding my initial question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic describes what StackOverflow is about. I can not see that I have broken any of the "rules" there. I have a specific software algorithm that I am trying to improve upon. If at all possible. The only way I see this possible is by using ASM, which for me is a specific programming problem in combination with Lazarus. And yes. I asked for help. Examples.. and no no. the code gurus don't like that. I don't understand why! The question should be easy enough!

Comment: And David. You may know some things about computers and how to make software, but you certainly don't know how to encourage people.
I have my fully functional software, using a structure I created myself from scratch. Even without assembler, this part of my SW is faster than any other similar software I have tested. I was going to share my finished routine and "brag a bit" about it when finished implementing ASM on the most CPU-demanding process, but now I don't even bother. As it goes, I don't need timing comparisons with ASM. The time can be calculated in needed CPU-cycles.

Comment: You have got all the advice that experts can give you. What you do with that is up to you.

Comment: If you don't understand our reaction (a reaction that is uniform from multiple sources), then shouldn't you try to work out where the disconnect is? This site isn't here to encourage people. It's about building a Q&A resource, as I have already mentioned. If we help askers along the way, then so much the better. But that's not the primary aim. So, with that knowledge, perhaps Stack Overflow is not for you. Maybe you need to look elsewhere for help. If Stack Overflow isn't giving you what you look for, please be our guest and find somewhere more suited to your needs. No problem in that.

Comment: @MortenBrendefur - You question looks like an [xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) to me. I'm sorry if you took it the wrong way, I was genuinely trying to help you.

Comment: Lieven Keersmaekers. I appreciate that. I suppose the answer was just yet another one in the line that doesn't help or answer the question, and worse, after I get worked up by David here.
Please accept my apologies for this.

Comment: And David... You say the site is not there to encourage people. Also, you add that it is about building a Q&A resource, but you point out that the primary aim is not to help people along the way... Uhhh. Where is the logic in that?
Anyway. Other people have given good links to sources I am investigating. From the looks of it, I am pretty sure that I can do this ASM-coding myself using some open source easy ASM-code as examples. It is after all examples I was after... and you know as well as I do that there are many approaches as to making this functionality in ASM. My question was valid.

Comment: Asking for code/examples without showing research effort is off-topic. You have had plenty of time to improve the question, but is incapable of understanding the message given here in comments.

Comment: Asking for examples is expressly off topic. As explained at the [help]. Do you care about this site or do you care only about your own needs?

Comment: There are no places in the help center where I find information about asking for examples being off topic.
Neither do I have problems understanding the messages some of you send. Just never mind. I am obviously at the totally wrong place. You will never have another question from me again. Sorry for trying to ask, and also sorry for trying to contribute to this site.

Comment: @Morten: Asking for people to write assembler code for you (and yes, that is what you are doing, indirectly), because you think the compiler generated code is too slow (although you never showed any proof, e.g. a disassembly, of that) is not "contributing to this site". It is just asking others to contribute to your perceived problem.

Comment: Rudy Velthuis. You and other people can read whatever you want into what I asked for. I asked very politely for examples of HOW this can be done. I have not one place asked for free complete work.
I learned everything I know about software developing from examples, looking at what other people did before me. To ask politely for examples of how to do things is NOT against anything explained in the terms of use for this site. My question has got nothing to do with what I think, it has got ALL to do with what I would like to try to do, and what I would like to try to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most optimizations come from [hoisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion) out invariant parts of code in the expression, and then performing strength reduction to decrease the number of variants. Learn to optimize Pascal before you go to assembler, even if only because disassembled Pascal gives you a skeleton for further assembler optimization and can act as comparison when testing the assembler code.

To better identify constant parts, we convert to a 0 based for loop with n=0..endposition-startposition, the expression then becomes:

```
FOR n := 0 TO EndPosition-StartPosition  DO 
  BEGIN
    Values[n+InsertOffset+StartPosition ] := Values[Index[n+StartPosition]];
  END;
```

Then we factor out the constant parts from the parts that are loop invariant, and introduce pointer syntax. T is the type of the values array, and PT is a pointer to it. Similarly, TI is the type of the index array and PTI is the pointer to it.

```
var StartValue : PT;
    StartIndex : PTI;  

StartValue:=@Values[InsertOffset+StartPosition]
StartIndex:=@Index[StartPosition];

FOR n := 0 TO EndPosition-StartPosition  DO 
    Startvalue[n]:=Values[StartIndex[n]]; // slightly depended on FPC dialect mode
```

Now, startvalue[n] is calculated as addressof(startvalue[0])+n*sizeof(T); However if we memorize the value of the address in the previous loop (in Startvalue) then the difference becomes PT:=PT+sizeof(T);

We transformed a multiplication into an add, but more importantly, we eliminated one variable from the expression (instead of startvalue and x (or n), we now only have startvalue to remember). This is called [strength reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction), and we can also apply this to the index array:

```
FOR n := 0 TO EndPosition-StartPosition  DO 
  begin
    Startvalue^:=Values[StartIndex^];
    inc(StartValue);   // inc increments with element size and we declared as PT, so this means inc(startvalue,sizeof(T));
    inc(StartIndex);
  end;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't eliminate the need for the values array altogether, but this loop has three values used in the loop (startvalue,startindex and values[]), while the original had many (index, values,x, startposition,insertoffset). In addition both have something to identify the end of iteration.

In our case that could be when startvalue reaches the end of the array, but for that we have to use a while:

```
 var StartValue,EndValue : PT;
     StartIndex : PTI;  

 StartValue:=@Values[InsertOffset+StartPosition]
 EndValue:=@Values[InsertOffset+EndPosition]
 StartIndex:=@Index[StartPosition];

 while (StartValue<=Endvalue) do
    begin
      Startvalue^:=Values[StartIndex^];
      inc(StartValue);   // inc increments with element size and we declared as PT, so this means inc(pbyte(startvalue),sizeof(T));
      inc(StartIndex);
    end;
```

In theory compilers can do these optimizations. C compilers often do when properly instructed, but most Pascal compilers are not yet up to that level. There however is no reason why they couldn't.

The best way to start assembler is to first optimize Pascal a lot and try to comprehend the generated code.

I've been doing image analysis in Delphi for years now, and going to assembler is only to manually correct the compiler not getting it (e.g. not hoisting or picking a suboptimal invariant), or when register allocation goes awol.

The only other case is whole image operations in SSE, but that doesn't apply here.

Comment: This answer stands out in usefulness. It is easy to grasp, and where I did not think my snippet of code could be simplified, the concepts at play here actually simplifies the moving of data by using a little bit more code, hence speeding up the code. Incredible!
It still doesn't answer my initial question, but in combination with other people's link to Agner Fog's asmlib and link to How to start using Inline ASM with FPC, I am where I would like to be on my project.

Comment: You could use inline assembler, but that would only frustrate the compiler, since the compiler wouldn't be able to keep its data in registers, a concept like gcc's register independent assembler macros doesn't exist in FPC atm. Note that FPC's move is already based on concept like Agner Fog's moves. But as PhiS says, the first job would be to see to rearrange your datastructures to see if you can actually move multiple in one go. E.g. if most entries in index map to sequential entries in values, maybe you can create some index that keeps track of ranges of records.

Comment: And start to inspect code at varying optimization levels using -al, and look at the assembler in the FPC RTL (i386/ and x86_64/ directories)

Comment: To rearrange the data-structure is something I will be working on, in particular trying to use an index as an array of bytes instead of an index as an array of integers. At least when shifting or moving one half of the Byte-index, that will reduce the needed bytes by 3/4th's.
To index sequential entries in values is possible, and absolutely worth looking into! but also quite a bit of work to implement. It will require several extra instructions per add, and not sure if this would justify only a possible marginal improvement on certain data. I believe it would give an overall penalty instead.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, before continuing, I think you would have to establish that the copying of data in this way is indeed the bottleneck and that there is no alternative strategy available that removes the need for copying altogether.

*If* you are certain that you need to have a faster copying routine, it is worth noting that these sort of optimisations can be very tricky and depend on hardware as well as the memory layout/alignment/data organisation and size. Without considerable experience or time, it is highly unlikely you would come up with a superior solution that is worth the effort.

However, optimised memory copy/move routines *are* available. In particular, you might want to look at Agner Fog's [asmlib](http://www.agner.org/optimize/), which contains optimised mem copy/move routines that can be called from compiled code.

Comment: It is the copying of data that is the bottleneck, the most CPU-demanding part of my code-snippet. though, I do have two choices.
1. Copy the indexed data in the index-order, or 2. Copy the indexed data in sequential order using Move, but then I also have to perform calculations on each and every Index-value in order to realign the index with the data. IF copying the indexed data in the index order, then the needed new index will simply be: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, etc, which I can set up in a separate array as a constant and simply use Move on :)

Comment: Agner Fog is not really relevant here since the biggest chunk copied is one integer. (due to the a[b[x]] double indirection expression. Moreover, FPC afaik already has a fairly decent move routine.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort - Maybe you're right (and I agree with your answer), but I don't know if the OP could just take a different logic in which case fewer, larger moves might do the trick. If so, AF's library is a good resource to know about.

Comment: Where as I don't know which move-function is the fastest, I do appreciate the link to AF's library. My main aim is to be able to inline simple ASM in FPC(Lazarus), but AF's library contain much that I can use as examples of assembler code in order to do what I would like to do. I just have to study a bit more :) In between work and family life :)

Comment: PhiS: the only thing I'd expect from AF is a move() and FPC's already is something similar (from Intel manuals), but he doesn't want to use it :-) So first benchmark FPC's mov before going to AF.